# MessageDialog crashes when called - Windows Phone Store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am having a message dialog to prompt the user when there is no internet.

```
public async void validateInternet()
{
    if (!isInternet())
    {
        Action cmdAction = null;
        MessageDialog _connectAlert = new MessageDialog("We are currently experiencing difficulties with your conectivity. Connect to internet and refresh again.", "No internet");
        _connectAlert.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Retry", (x) => { cmdAction = () => validateInternet(); }));
        _connectAlert.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
        _connectAlert.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
        await _connectAlert.ShowAsync();
        cmdAction.Invoke();
    }
}

public static bool isInternet()
{
    ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    bool internet = connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;
    return internet;
}
```

Now, I call this function `validateInternet` when MainPage has loaded. The app opens the message dialog, and crashes immediately. What's wrong with the code?

A `A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in BusTrack.exe Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`
is thrown at

```
await _connectAlert.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the code itself. It works fine in both Page.Loaded and OnNavigatedTo. Where exactly are you calling it? From the UI thread?

Comment: I am calling it from `public MainPage()`. I tried calling it from `MainPage_Loaded` too. Same error

Comment: Well, this seems to be working for me. Is the `validateInternet` method the only thing that you call in the `Loaded` handler? This exception happens if you try to show a dialog, while another dialog is already displayed. Unrelated to that - cmdAction will be null if you don't press "retry" and will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: My MainPage_loaded has async keyword. MainPage_Loaded has nothing else. So, is there a limit to how many async functions calling async functions?

Comment: You caught the mistake. I call `validateInternet()` in both `MainPage_Loaded` and `OnNavigatedTo()`. Hence, two message boxes, resulting to the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As @yasen rightly pointed out, the `validateInternet()` was called both in `MainPage_loaded()` and `OnNavigatedTo()`.

Hence, `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` occurs since both of those methods will try to show a `messageDialog`. So, never try to call two message dialogs at the same time.